# Bootstrap 4 custom table css style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a custom css for a bootstrap 4 table that wont affect the other standard bootstrap tables.
What is the css code for this table set that I can make a custom css set for all elements?

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped table-hover"><table>
```

Comment: What is your question? You seem to be asking "How do I use and apply CSS".

Comment: you can add class to table and then style it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the table an `id` or `class` and then set the styling with the `id` as the anchor.

See the following answer:

[fastest way to use css for html table without affecting another html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016409/fastest-way-to-use-css-for-html-table-without-affecting-another-html-table)